# Get a lot of data (200M rows) from SQL Server in Python

Tags: python, sql-server

I am facing the following issue: I have a really large dataset (+200M rows, dozens of columns) that I have to retrieve from SQL Server.

The current way I'm doing it is this way:

```
from pyodbc import connect
from pandas import read_sql

def get_table(query, server,
          database="", driver="SQL Server Native Client 11.0"):

cnxn_str = ("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
            "Server="+server+";"
            "Database="+database+";"
            "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
cnxn = connect(cnxn_str)
return read_sql(query, cnxn)
```

This function runs fine for up to hundreds of thousands of data, but I can't make it return even 1M rows. Every time I have a very large dataset, the following error returns (translated from portuguese):

```
OperationalError: ('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]TCP Provider: A connection atempt failed because a connected component did not respond correctly after a period of time.
```

Note that to connect to SQL Server, the local code actually use Windows authentication, that's why I don't have to pass any user or pwd.

I also tried to use chunksize, but got the same result.

Is there any way I can do this efficiently?

Comment: What does your SQL statement look like? Are you using `WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)`? Are you using `fetchone()`, `fetchall()`, or `fetchmany()`?

Comment: I would try to save the results to file system before loading them to pandas. 200M is quite a lot of rows in a df.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html Reading the docs, it seems that the con only supports sqlite3 object, not sql server. Have you confirmed that this is not an issue?

Comment: I have a simple query, something like "SELECT * FROM DB..TABLE". And yeah! I thought about separating chunks and saving them into storage before loading on pandas, but I was wondering if there's a more "straightforward" way.

Comment: I don't think it have to do with SQLite3. The limit of rows for sqlite3 is 2^64, way larger than what I have. Also, I tried getting data not from pandas, but directly from pyodbc, and got the exact same error. It seems to be that the connection with SQL Server runs out after a time. If all data wasn't retrieved in this time period, the whole proccess crashes.

Comment: Check out timeout settings perhaps?

Comment: Is the query only `SELECT * FROM DB..TABLE` or does it have something like `ORDER BY Something` on the end? The former will immediately start streaming results, the latter will need to sort the results on SQL Server first (which takes time) and for 200 million rows that don't have a suitable covering index may well be hitting command timeouts in pyodbc.

Comment: Aside... you may wish to move away from [SQL Server Native Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/sql-server-native-client) as soon as possible. Microsoft hasn't provided any feature updates for it since SQL Server 2012 and has **finally** removed it entirely from SQL Server 2022 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

try using a cursor.  A cursor fetches one row at a time.

```
 conn = pyodbc.connect(
        r'DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
        r'SERVER=' + server + ';'
        r'DATABASE=' + database + ';'
        r'UID=' + user + ';'
        r'PWD=' + password
    )
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select * from " + table)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    
    ... process the rows

    or try

conn = pyodbc.connect(
        r'DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
        r'SERVER=' + server + ';'
        r'DATABASE=' + database + ';'
        r'UID=' + user + ';'
        r'PWD=' + password
    )
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select * from " + table)
    while True:
        rows = cursor.fetchmany(chunksize)
        if not rows:
            break
        for row in rows:
            yield row
```